# Empty render with OpenGL on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to render a scene using OpenGL ES 2.0 in an Android App, however, the screen keeps being drawn with the defined clear color.

I had success rendering simpler examples, but I'm failing when using packed vertex buffer.

The idea is to render a scene with a camera inside a Sphere, here are some code snippets which should give some context and also is where I think the bug is.

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform  inputImageTexture;
void main()
{
  vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vTextureCoord);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
}
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uTransform;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition * vec4(1, -1, 1, 1);
  vec4 coord = (aTextureCoord / 2.0) + 0.5;
  vTextureCoord = (uTransform * coord).xy;
}
```

**The GL program initialization:**

```
mProgram = new ProgramObject();
if(mProgram.init(vsh, fshResult)) {
   GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
   GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
   uMVPMatrixLocation = mProgram.getUniformLoc("uMVPMatrix");
   aPositionLocation = mProgram.attributeLocation("aPosition");
   aTextureCoordLocation = mProgram.attributeLocation("aTextureCoord");
   mTransformLoc = mProgram.getUniformLoc("uTransform");
}
```

**Vertex loading:**

```
sphere = new Sphere(SPHERE_SLICES, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, SPHERE_RADIUS, SPHERE_INDICES_PER_VERTEX);
mProgram.bind();
final int buffers[] = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);
mVertexBuffer = buffers[0];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphere.getVerticesSize(), sphere.getVertices(), GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

**Render:**

```
GLES20.glViewport(viewport.x, viewport.y, viewport.width, viewport.height);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(TEXTURE_2D_BINDABLE, texID);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, sphere.getVerticesStride(), sphere.getVertices());

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordLocation);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoordLocation, 2,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, sphere.getVerticesStride(),
    sphere.getVertices().duplicate().position(3));

Matrix.multiplyMM(pvMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, pvMatrix, 0, modelMatrix , 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVPMatrixLocation, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

for (int j = 0; j < sphere.getNumIndices().length; ++j) {
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, sphere.getNumIndices()[j], GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sphere.getIndices()[j]);
}
```

Any insights are welcome, thank you very much.

**Update**

The could was running without any errors on a Galaxy S6, but, now running on a One Plus X I'm getting the following error:

```
<gl_draw_error_checks:598>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glDrawElements: glError 0x502
```

After running:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sphere.getNumIndices().length; ++j) {
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, sphere.getNumIndices()[j], GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sphere.getIndices()[j]);
}
```

Comment: Does getVerticesSize correctly return the size in bytes of the vertices array? Also have you checked results from glGetError?

Comment: It seems to be returning the correct value. Trying to run the same code on another phone I got error `glError 0x505` after `GLES20.glDrawElements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two ways of using vertex arrays:

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
...
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, sphere.getVerticesStride(), sphere.getVertices());
```

In ES 2.0, there are two ways of using vertex arrays:

- Client-side vertex arrays.
- Vertex-buffer objects (VBOs).

With client-side vertex arrays, you don't store your vertex data in VBOs, but pass the vertex data directly as the last argument to the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call. In C/C++ bindings, this is a pointer to the data, in the Java bindings it's a Java `Buffer` object.

When using VBOs, you store your vertex data in a VBO, using `glBufferData()`. Then you bind the VBO before the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call, and pass the **offset of the data relative to the start of the VBO** as the last argument.

In your example:

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, sphere.getVerticesStride(), 0);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordLocation);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoordLocation, 2,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, sphere.getVerticesStride(), 12);
```

Note that the offset is in bytes, so it's 12 bytes if your colors are offset by 3 floats relative to the positions.

Client-side vertex arrays are deprecated, and partly unavailable, in newer versions of OpenGL. So storing the data in VBOs, as you already are, is the right way to go.